# Have an issue with the designed menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following menu that properly works. All I need is that once an item is selected or hovered its whole section be highlighted in all sizes of screen. At the moment just partial part of each item get highlighted.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">



<style>

.container-menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(0,0,0);
    min-height: 63px;
}

.menu-items {
    max-width: 1130px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; //
    text-align: center;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-items li {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.menu-items #home {
    background-color: green;
}
.menu-items {
    position: relative;
}

.menu-items a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-items ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-items li {
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu-items li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.burger {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    display: none;
}

.menu-items li:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-items ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu-items li {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
    }
    .container-menu>img {
        display: none;
    }
}


@media ( min-width :1500px) {
    .menu-items li {
        padding: 8px 38px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width : 979px) and (max-width:1500px) {
    .menu-items li {
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        display: inline;
        padding: 8px 15px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width : 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

    .menu-items li {
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        display: inline;
        padding: 8px 15px;
    }
    .item {
        height: 186px !important;
    }

}

@media ( max-width : 767px) {

    .container-menu {
        min-height: 63px;
    }
    .menu-items li {
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 8px 12px;
    }

}

@media ( max-width : 480px) {
    .container-menu {
        min-height: 48px;
    }
    .menu-top-center {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu-top-right {
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
}
</style>
</head>


<body>


<header>
    <div class="container-menu">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <ul id="">
                <li id="home"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home f24"></i>
                        Home</a></li>
                <li id="item1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li id="item2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li id="mitem3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li id="item4"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li id="item5"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li id="item6"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                <li id="item7"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger hidden-md">
                <i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.burger').click(function() {
                $('.menu-items ul').toggleClass("visible");
            });
        });
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Negative vote without any explanation is terrible do you know that? :D

Comment: 1. No idea what image. Changing image could not change other items.
2. All items same width
3. .menuitems ul li {width: 200px} works fine.

Comment: can't able to visualize your output, Please add any screen shot to understand your output

Comment: @Justinas 1.sample image is provided 2.How come last item background does not reach the left side of screen? 3.how about different screen sizes?

Comment: Your output doesn't show the content of `<a>` tag i.e.(
Item 1. Item2, etc)

Comment: @Dimple thats my issue with jsfiddle, there is a 'result' icon on the top left corner of result window that is overlapping my button.

Comment: try [opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Comment: Terrible design, with no thought in regards to UI/UX. The colour scheme is gaudy and that curved image costs you bandwidth without actually doing anything. The idea of a menu is to get people where they want to go, not be a distraction and detract attention away from the actual content.

Comment: @MatthewRath I am experimenting. This is not an actual design.

Comment: I am wondering what are these negative votes for?

Comment: Display something what you want in mobile view

Comment: @VigneshBala at the moment, partial part of the selected item's (Home) row is highlighted I would like to highlight the whole row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the issue by adding following code

```
.menu-items li{
   padding:16px 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I have completely redesigned new Navigation bar as per your images. Please have a look.

- It is 100% responsive
- working fine in large screen
- in mobile view, I have disabled collapse of navigation bar so design will be same in smaller devices

```css
body {
  line-height: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li,
.navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}
.navbar > .container {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.navbar-header,
.navbar-brand,
.navbar .navbar-nav,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block!important;
  width: auto !important;
  clear: none !important;
}
.navbar {
  position: relative !important;
}
.back-stripe {
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 999999;
  background-image: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/2yvucqw.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.navbar-default {
  background: #4C0084 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #FFA600;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFA600;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
  background: #FFA600 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background: #FFA600 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="back-stripe"></div>
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 3%;margin-top:-4px;">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item7</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, as explained in the question I need to have a burger style menu, how to add that to your design. Also all menu items should be in one line in your design the last items go to the second line.

Comment: @Jack what the fun is that burger style menu?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Creating-An-Off-canvas-Navigation-Menu-With-jQuery-CSS3.html

Comment: so you want that in mobile view?? @Jack

Comment: yes and I have it in my code, please refer to this part  $('.burger').click(function()

Comment: Bootstrap rears its ugly (and massive) head once again. Duck and cover.

Comment: @JacobGray what do you mean?

Comment: @eirenaios what to do in mobile any ideas?

Comment: @Jack haha, sorry. I just really dislike bootstrap. :D

Comment: @eirenaios just awarded the bounty but still has issue with menu in mobile screens. :(

Comment: @eirenaios the question is again for a 100 bounty award.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed your issue. Try use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">
<style>
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container-m-tp {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}
.container-m-btn {
    width: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(75, 0, 130);
    min-height: 62px;
}
.container-m-btn>img {
    max-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.m-tp {
    max-width: 970px;
    max-width: 1237px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.m-btn {
    max-width: 1900px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
.m-btn li:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
.m-tp-center {
    display: inline-block;
    //
    width: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
.m-tp-right {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    //
    width: 200px;
    //
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.m-btn {
    position: relative;
}
.m-btn a {
    color: #fff;
}
.m-btn ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.m-btn li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 25px 32px 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.m-btn li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.burger {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(img/burger.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
    .container-m-btn {
        min-height: 40px;
    }
    .m-btn ul {
        display: none;
        border-top: 1px #fff solid;
    }
    .m-btn li {
        display: block;
        border: none;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        border-bottom: 1px #fff solid;
    }
    .m-btn li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .container-m-btn>img {
        display: none;
    }
}
.m-btn .visible {
    display: block;
}
.m-btn li:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
.m-btn li:active {
    background-color: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container-m-btn">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRNPb.png" />
            <div class="m-btn">
                <ul id="">
                    <li id="item1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home f24"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li id="item2"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                    <li id="item3"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                    <li id="item4"><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
                    <li id="item5"><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
                    <li id="item6"><a href="#">Item6</a></li>
                    <li id="item7"><a href="#">Item7</a></li>
                    <li id="item8"><a href="#">Item8</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="burger"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <style>
        .m-btn #item7 {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <p>This is body</p>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.burger').click(function() {
        $('.m-btn ul').toggleClass("visible");
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not have anything extra compare to other answers. Please have a look at the screenshots in the question.\

Answer (score 0):

> If I change the top horizontal image to a curvy one the height of white borders of menu items would be too short for that, I need them to be a bit taller. (no clue)

//unclear, are you looking for this ?

[image]

//added border-bottom to the @media li,

```
.menuitems li {
        display: block;
       border-left:0px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    }
```

> In burger style the width of the last item is a bit short. (No idea why)

// add `padding:0` to UL to remove empty space in first tab

```
.menuitems ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;

}
```

> I need to make all menu items a bit wider. (Changing width did not work)

```
 .menuitems li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 35px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    width:80px;
}
```

Comment: @Jack,edited my answer, are you looking for the same ?

Comment: Regarding border heights, I mean when the screen is in full size, you can see the image above the menu. What I would like to have is to have the height of menu a bit higher. In this way the borders would be higher. Then I would have the text of menu items in just 2px from button of the menu. At the end, the image should overlap the top part of the menu bar that does not have any text.

Comment: @Jack, there is no curvy image in your jsfiddle . You can add height to UL . If you want to make menu height a bit higher

Comment: It did it solve the isssue, will try that again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update these lines into your styles

```
.m-btn ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

It worked for me.....

**EDIT**

Or try this one

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .m-btn ul {
      padding: 0;
    }
}
```